# How can I use a loop inside a boundary condition in NDSolveValue?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions, do

How can I use the variable `i` of a "do" loop inside a boundary condition in `NDSolveValue`, and plot the solution for each step? I have tried this code:

```
NDSolveValue[{
    (* Your differential equations here *)
    D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
    u[0, x] == Sin[x],
    u[t, 0] == 0,
    u[t, 1] == i
  }, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not use a `Do` and loop. I would use Manipulate. But if you want a do loop. But be careful, for some values pf your `i` you will get this warning from NDSolve

> ParametricNDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions
> are inconsistent.

Because you will be setting a BC in your loop which is not consistent depending on its value.

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x];
ic = {u[0, x] == Sin[x], u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == i}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{pde, ic}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {i}];
data = Flatten@Last@Reap@Do[
      p = 
       Plot3D[Evaluate[u[i][t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u[t,x]"}];
      Sow[Labeled[p, Row[{"i=", i}]]], {i, 0, 8, 1}];
Grid[Partition[data, 3], Spacings -> 5, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `Table` instead of `Do` loop.